# Error - ''This condition will always return false since the types ''string'' and ''number'' have no overlap''

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following code, which is a component for my website which shows the detailed creditcard information about a user:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CreditCardService } from 'src/app/credit-card-service.service';
import { TransactionService } from 'src/app/transaction.service';
import { CreditCard, Transaction } from 'src/app/creditCardType'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-credit-card-item',
  templateUrl: './credit-card-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./credit-card-item.component.css']
  })
 export class CreditCardItemComponent implements OnInit {

   public creditCard: CreditCard | undefined;
   creditCard$!: Observable<CreditCard | undefined>;
   transactions$!: Observable<Transaction[]>;
   transaction: Transaction[] | undefined;


  id: number = -1;
  creditCardNumber!: number;

  constructor(private _creditCardService: CreditCardService,
    private ac: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private _transactionService: TransactionService) {

    this.ac.params.subscribe(params=> {
    this.creditCardNumber = parseInt(params.creditCardNumber);

    this.creditCard$ = this._creditCardService.getCreditCards().pipe(
      map(cc=>cc.find(c => c.card_number === this.creditCardNumber)));

    this.transactions$ = this._transactionService.getTransactions().pipe(
      map(transactions =>
        transactions.filter(transaction => transaction.credit_card.card_number === 
         this.creditCardNumber)
          )
        );
      });
    }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.id = this.ac.snapshot.params.id;
  this.creditCard = this._creditCardService.getCreditCard(this.id);

  this._transactionService.getTransactions().subscribe(value => this.transaction = 
  value);
  }

deleteCreditCard() {
  this._creditCardService.deleteCreditCard(this.id).subscribe(value => 
  console.log(value));
  this.router.navigate([''])
 }
}
```

It is the line:
''c => c.card_number === this.creditCardNumber'' and transaction => transaction.credit_card.card_number === this.creditCardNumber, which gives me the error ''this condition will always return false since the types ''string'' and ''number'' have no overlap''  which i dont understand why since i have been using this code to other similar cases where it is working

Comment: The clue is in the error - you are using strict comparison `===` when comparing a string to a number. That will never work. Since you know the items being compared should be numbers, you should cast them as numbers first and then use strict comparison, like `c => +c.card_number === +this.creditCardNumber`

Answer (score -1):

Ok, you are checking the value and type of data to be compared.

Just do it like this

```
c => c.card_number == this.creditCardNumber
```

it will only compare values here and if you still get error,

```
c => c.card_number === this.creditCardNumber.toString()
```

Comment: what is wrong with this approach ?

Comment: Well, it worked fine for me, thank you!

Comment: I cant do it, because im new and need more reputation to do , thats why i wrote a comment instead:)